# Sshing into a server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh

I have noticed that after upgrading my laptop (not sure if this is the reason) to 18.04 Ubuntu, I have not been able to ssh to an institute server although I'm able to on the same internet network from a desktop computer.

When "ssh -v" is applied the following is the result before timing out:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxxxx.xxx.edu [128.118.xxx.xxx] port 22.
```

I have tried deleting the known_hosts file, as it was one of the suggestions on the internet. However, it did not resolve this issue. Any tips that might help fix the problem are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: 'institute server' - is it on the same network?  what happens when you try?  Can you ping the remote server directly?

Comment: I am able to ping the remote server.

Comment: Yes, the institute server is on the same network

Comment: The institute had made some recent changes to the firewall and had recommended the use of a VPN. I have installed and used that VPN, the VPN service connects successfully, but when I try Sshing, this error is returned: ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx.xxxx.xxx.edu: Name or service not known. I am also not able to browse the internet

Comment: If you are already on the same network, there should be no need to connect through VPN. VPN is typically used for connections from outside to the destination network. Maybe does "ssh -v" help to debug the issue? Do you use private+public keys for authentication or password?

Comment: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxxxx.xxx.edu [128.118.xxx.xxx] port 22.

Comment: The above is the output with -v flag applied. And it remains stuck there until it times out

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson it's likely then you need a VPN and then they only accept that VPN's subnet to connect via firewall rules.  Use the VPN to test.

Comment: @OliverR. That's not necessarily the case if they firewall it off to only allow the VPN-tunneled connections in.  There're many cases this is done, including at various companies and education departments at the university level sometimes.

Comment: @ThomasWard With the VPN, the following error is returned: ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx.xxxxx.xxx.edu: Name or service not known. Weirdly, I'm able to ping the server though.

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson do you know the IP address for the server offhand?  Try connecting with the IP instead of the hostname (the VPN might not be providing a DNS server for you to properly use)

Comment: @ThomasWard. I can't thank you enough, that resolved the issue. However, this issue seems to have arisen recently, is this something that should be suggested to the institute or is it dependent on the OS?

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson lack of a DNS server for you to resolve hostnames is an issue on the Institute's side of the VPN, they need to define a DNS server that the VPN subnet can reach that can do the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two things to consider:

1. If the server hosts (the Institute) now say you should use a VPN to access the system, then it's quite likely that they are disallowing access from the rest of the same shared network and requiring you to use the VPN to pass traffic to the server first.  In this case, you have no choice but to use the VPN.

   However, given that you couldn't resolve the host name, the second part to consider is...
2. There is no DNS server on the VPN connection that can handle resolving the hostname that you're entering.

   This means the people running the VPN need to set up a DNS server on the VPN and specify it in the VPN connection to resolve the hostname to an IP address.

   In the interim you can use the direct IP address for the server for your connections, and if you're over the VPN that should give you access to the server.